# How to verify a JWT using python PyJWT with a public PEM cert?

Tags: python, rsa, jwt, pem

I recently upgraded from PyJWT 0.4.1 to 1.0.1 and I can't figure out how to verify a JWT signed with a public key.

My code looks like this:

```
import jwt
cert_string = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICITCCAYqgAwIBAgIIBEsUSxL..."
token_string = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6I..."
jwt.decode(token_string, cert_string, algorithms=['RS256'])
```

The error I get is:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api.py", line 117, in decode                            
key, algorithms, **kwargs)                                                                                         
File "~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api.py", line 176, in _verify_signature                 
key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)                                                                                     
File "~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 165, in prepare_key                
key = load_pem_public_key(key, backend=default_backend())                                                          
File "~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py", line 24, in load_pem_public_key
return backend.load_pem_public_key(data)                                                                           
File "~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py", line 285, in load_pem_public_key
return b.load_pem_public_key(data)
File "~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 716, in load_pem_public_key
self._handle_key_loading_error()
File "~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 912, in _handle_key_loading_error
raise ValueError("Could not unserialize key data.")                                                                
ValueError: Could not unserialize key data.
```

I'm confident my cert_string and token are good. The following code runs OK:

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_string, default_backend())
```

My code that used to work with 0.4.1 looked like this:

```
cert_string = "".join(cert_string.strip().split("\n")[1:-1])
der = a2b_base64(cert_string)
cert = DerSequence()
cert.decode(der)
tbsCertificate = DerSequence()
tbsCertificate.decode(cert[0])
subjectPublicKeyInfo = tbsCertificate[6]
pub_key = RSA.importKey(subjectPublicKeyInfo)
jwt.decode(token_string, pub_key)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to pass the public key instead of the full certificate to the decode method. So extract the key from the certificate in order to use it as in:

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

cert_str = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIIDETCCAfm..."
cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_str, default_backend())
public_key = cert_obj.public_key()
```

and then:

```
token_string = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6I..."
jwt.decode(token_string, public_key, algorithms=['RS256'])
```

Comment: getting error `TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char[]' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str`

Comment: This worked for me but my certificate needed the \n in the certificate. e.g. `cert_str =  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDHDCCAgSgAwIBAgIIUAu/wmcX4dQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwMTEvMC0GA1UE\nAxMmc2...`

Comment: In Python 3 `load_pem_x509_certificate` is expecting `cert_str` to be bytes rather than a string. If you pass it a string you get `TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object`

Comment: In Python3, the fix is to suffix encode to your keys, i.e. cert_obj.encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 3):

If the key file is generated using  `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (RFC4716), you can use the file directly.

**Encode:**

```
import jwt

pemfile = open("id_rsa", 'r')
keystring = pemfile.read()
pemfile.close()
token = jwt.encode(payload, keystring, algorithm='RS256')
```

**Decode:**

```
import jwt

pemfile = open("id_rsa.pub", 'r')
keystring = pemfile.read()
pemfile.close()
payload = jwt.decode(toekn, keystring,  verify=True)
```

dont forget to catch errors like `jwt.ExpiredSignatureError` etc

Answer (score 1):

I am using python 3.6

```
import jwt
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
key = b"""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBI....<<Your public key basically>>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""
public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(key, backend=default_backend())
print(jwt.decode(token, public_key))
```

This worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, with Python 3.6 (don't ask) I get
  Message=from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object